# I fond a merge linked list solution online, but I don't really understand the while loop

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I have got the merge function online, but I don't really understand the condition in the while loop. So, for (L1 !== null && L2 !== null), I am not sure what is **L1 !== null** actually checking. Is it checking whether the first node of linkedList L1 has a value or not, or is it checking whether the linkedList L1 is a linkedList? Any why? Can someone take a look at it? thanks

```
function merge(L1, L2) {

  var L3 = new Node(null, null);
  var prev = L3;

  while (L1 !== null && L2 !== null) {
    if (L1.data <= L2.data) { 
      prev.next = L1;
      L1 = L1.next;
    } else {
      prev.next = L2;
      L2 = L2.next;
    }
    prev = prev.next;
  }

  if (L1 === null) { prev.next = L2; }
  if (L2 === null) { prev.next = L1; }

  return L3.next;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `L1 !== null` determines if L1 is null.   The while loop is running until either L1 or L2 are null, meaning one of them has fully been merged.  Immediately after the loop, the rest of the non-null Linked List is then also merged.